# Segmentation fault when run django celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to run https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/examples/django

when I'm doing

`celery -A proj worker -l info`

I'm getting the following

```
 -------------- celery@gegham-Inspiron-3542 v3.1.18 (Cipater)

---- **** -----

--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.13.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty

-- * - **** --- 

- ** ---------- [config]

- ** ---------- .> app:         proj:0x7fbc67e8da50

- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//

- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled

- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)

-- ******* ---- 

--- ***** ----- [queues]

 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]

  . demoapp.tasks.add

  . demoapp.tasks.mul

  . demoapp.tasks.xsum

  . proj.celery.debug_task


[2015-09-05 08:27:56,262: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to 

amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//

[2015-09-05 08:27:56,267: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can you help to resolve this

Comment: Is there any suspicious output when doing `celery -A proj worker -l debug`?

Comment: again get segmentation fault

Comment: wht kind of result should I expect?

Comment: Anything vaguely related really. Might help updating your original question with the debug output, but for me I can't make anything out of this.

Comment: @gjivanya: I recommend monitoring your memory usage to see if you are running out of RAM. Try using `htop` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Helped:

Remove `python-librabbitmq`:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-librabbitmq
```

Install `librabbitmq` via pip:

```
sudo pip install librabbitmq
```

Comment: A little late to the party but this worked for me:
`sudo service rabbit-mq-server restart`